# How do I center my SignUp From in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am attempting to center this [Bootstrap form](https://jsfiddle.net/j3vnehs2/6/).

I want the input fields and button to be aligned to the center of the DOM.

```
<div>                
    <div class = "container">                    
        <div>                             
            <form class = "">        
                <div  class = "row">          
                    <div class = "form-group">          
                        <input  type = "email" class = "form-control input-lg" placeholder = "Enter email address "/>        
                    </div>   
                </div>
                <div  class = "row">              
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <input  type = "password" class = "form-control input-lg" placeholder = "Enter password" /> 
                    </div>            
                    <input type = "submit" class = "btn btn-info btn-lg"/>
                </div>                              
            </form> 
        </div> 
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div align="">
      <form class="text-center">
        <div class="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter email address " />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter password" />
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using position: absolute, transform: translateX and transform: translateY

This will center the form vertically and horizontally.

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 100vh;">                
<div class = "container" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); text-align:center;">
....
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; height: 100vh;">                
    <div class = "container" style="position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); text-align:center;
">                    
        <div>                             
            <form class = "">        
                <div  class = "row">          
                    <div class = "form-group">          
                        <input  type = "email" class = "form-control input-lg" placeholder = "Enter email address "/>        
                    </div>   
                </div>
                <div  class = "row">              
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <input  type = "password" class = "form-control input-lg" placeholder = "Enter password" /> 
                    </div>            
                    <input type = "submit" class = "btn btn-info btn-lg"/>
                </div>                              
            </form> 
        </div> 
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the outer div form a fixed width and center it this way:

```
.outerDiv{
   width: 300px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Check the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cl_moises/L4og4gme/)

Answer (score 0):

Same here.. Use this .

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <div>                
        <div class = "container">                    
            <div>                             
                <form class = "text-center">        
                    <div  class = "row">          
                        <div class = "form-group">          
                            <input  type = "email" class = "form-control input-lg" placeholder = "Enter email address "/>        
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                    <div  class = "row">              
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <input  type = "password" class = "form-control input-lg" placeholder = "Enter password" /> 
                        </div>            
                        <input type = "submit" class = "btn btn-info btn-lg"/>
                    </div>                              
                </form> 
            </div> 
        </div>  
    </div>
     <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```